# Take a TD, and insert it after the second TD in the parent TR

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a table. I want to take **all** ninth TDs in each TR, and place it after the first original TD in that same TR.

This code takes the ninth TD, and places it right after the parent TR. I want to place it after the first original TD in that same TR:

```
$('td:nth-child(9)').each( function(){
   $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

What I need is an equivalent of:

```
.parent():first-child
```

Comment: Do you want the ninth `td` to become the second `td` or placed *after* the original second `td`?

Comment: I messed up, sorry. I want it to be places after the first original TD. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('td:nth-child(9)').each( function(){
    $(this).siblings('td:first').after(this);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nyqE/2/)

Comment: `siblings('td:eq(0)')` even shorter.

Comment: @VisioN - good catch, moved the eq into the selector! The question seems to change every five minutes!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('td:nth-child(9)').each( function(){

            $(this).siblings('td').eq(0).after(this);
 });
```